# Computing the index $[\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z}) : \Gamma(N)]$

Tags: automorphic-forms

Hi I have a question about congruence subgroups $Γ(N)$ of $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$.

How to compute the index $[SL(2,\mathbb{Z}): Γ(N)]$?

BTW, can anyone tell me double cosets decomposition $\sigma^{-1}_{a}\Gamma\sigma_{b}$, where $a$ and $b$ are two cusps and $\sigma$ is an element in $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

As far as I remember: *A First Course in Modular Forms* by Diamond and Shurman explains this in the first chapter. Miyake and Shimura probaly also address this as well in their books on modular forms.

*The following strategy works for GL(N) and SL(N) as well.*

First of all, $\Gamma(N)$ is normal in $\Gamma(1)=SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ with the quotient being isomorphic to $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/N)$.

Next, the isomorphism
$$\mathbb{Z}/N \cong \bigoplus_{p^k || N} \mathbb{Z}/p^k$$
induces an isomorphism
$$ SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/N) \cong \bigoplus\limits_{p^k || N} SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/p^k).$$

Then if $k=1$, we have by the Bruhat decomposition of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/p)$ the following coset decomposition
$$ SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/p) = B(\mathbb{Z}/p) \amalg  N(\mathbb{Z}/p) w_0 B(\mathbb{Z}/p)$$
for $B$ being the upper diagonal, and $N$ the strict upper diagonal matrices. So the cardinality is here $p(p-1) + p^2(p-1)$. The element $w_0$ is the Weyl element, i.e., zeros on the diagonal and $\pm 1$ on the antidiagonal (the order doesn't matter).

For $k \geq 2$, you should also apply the Iwahori decomposition of $\Gamma_0(p)$ together with
$$ SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) = \Gamma_0(p) \amalg  \Gamma_1(p) w_0 \Gamma_0(p).$$

I leave the computation for $k \geq 2$ as an exercise to you.

(Caution, this is for $GL(2)$) You can also look at lemma 1 in http://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2FBF01355984.pdf